# Running docker-compose with mysql and own docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I am trying to start my own container and link it with the official mysql container. I am using docker-compose to start both containers and link them together. My own container is supposed to be a regular LAMP-stack which runs a simple PHP application.

When I run `docker-compose up`, they both build properly, but when docker tries to run them, they just stop with the error code `mytestservice_web_1 exited with code 0`. I can not see any errors in the build log.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  build: .
  links:
    - mysql
  ports:
    - "80:80"

mysql:
  image: mysql:5.6
  environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=verysecret
```

Here is my Dockerfile for my own container.

```
FROM linode/lamp
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN a2enmod rewrite
ADD . /var/www/mytestservice
ADD mytestservice.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
CMD service apache2 start
```

If I start them manually with docker run there are no problems.

How can I keep the containers running?

Comment: My guess is the `:` in `mysql:5.6` is throwing off the yaml syntax. Try wrapping it in quotes: `image: "mysql:5.6"`

Comment: That didn't work. I think the problem is that I do not specify that the containers shall keep on running. I am running a lamp image which does not have a clear way to keep running, unless I start it with bash.

Comment: Yeah your CMD is wrong, it should start apache as a foreground process.

Comment: For example: `exec /usr/sbin/apachectl -D FOREGROUND`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above:

```
CMD exec /usr/sbin/apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```